# One Hot Encoding uses R if the column has multiple values

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Starting with this data set:

[image]

and I hope to make it look like
[image]

I use the syntax

```
library(caret)
dummy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data=data)
newdata <- data.frame(predict(dummy, newdata = data))
```

but the result like

[image]

How can I have the result like the end dataset?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, using the output of `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt, without the data being provided:

```
mydf <- data.frame(var = c("eggs, bread", "milk, bread, cream"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf |> 
  mutate(id = row_number(), placeholder = 1) |> 
  separate_rows(var) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = placeholder, values_fill = 0)


# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id  eggs bread  milk cream
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0
2     2     0     1     1     1
```